# Getting subform control value in Access

Tags: ms-access

I have a subform placed inside a form called "UpdateStudentListing" in my application. The subform is called "Family_T subform". The subform loops through multiple records and shows multiple sets of fields related to each record.

I need to grab a value from one of my fields, "DL_Pic_Location", in the active form when a control in that same looped form is clicked. How do I specify that far down? Currently I'm only able to retrieve the value of the first printed form in the list of all repeated sets of data in the subform.

Thanks.

EDIT::

TO clarify, this subform has the "Cycle" setting in the Property Sheet set to "All Records", and I need to get the value of a control inside the same form as the control that was clicked was contained inside.

Comment: Sorry I totally misunderstood your question. I thought it was about getting the value of a control on a subform. So I deleted that answer.  But I still don't understand what you actually want. Showing us some code might help.

Comment: In essence, I'm referencing an image on a network drive with a path contained in a field within each cycled entry in the subform. Clicking the image control allows the user to overwrite the image that's currently linked:

strPath = Forms!UpdateStudentListing![Family_T subform]!DL_Pic_Location.Value

This is used for defining the path to use for the image within each cycled record. My only remaining problem is to have Access properly grab data from the record whose image control was just clicked. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: *"the record whose image control was just clicked"*  Is that the subform's current record?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the "current record" at this point is the first record in the list, unless another record in the subform has a focused field. In that case, the record which was last "focused" becomes the current record. I need to control the current record based on which record just had its image control clicked.

Comment: when you click ANY control in looped form, current record sets to that which data section is clicked.